# Unable to start Ubuntu. Unknown Job

Tags: startup, cron

I'm new to Ubuntu. It asked me to reboot because of updates. Now it doesn't start at all.

[image]

I've managed to get to GRUB.

[image]

I went to previous versions, and selected the only one available (3.5.0-23), which gave me pretty much the same error:

[image]

Then I went into recovery mode > "dpkg", which ended with the same error after some loading.

Comment: go to grub at statrup and try to go to the recovery mode. Is root shell accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the previous version of Ubuntu on your system? If not, then try to do so when your system starts up and select it from Grub. If it's not there, then enter the advanced options for Ubuntu and select the previous kernel version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Just found out about Grub. So far not helping. I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: I've got it to start! Mixing different things I found online, I've managed to access the command-line, edited the file "/etc/X11/default-display-manager" to contain "/usr/sbin/lightdm" instead of "/usr/sbin/gdm". I'm not sure what it all means but I see the desktop. Most likely related to multiple-monitor stuff.

Comment: Ok, I guess it was a problem with your display manager, and by choosing the light display manager(lightdm) it must have fixed the issue. You were using the gnome display manager before(gdm). Did you by any chance configure your etc files by mistake?...Well, good thing you got it working :).

Comment: Display manager is the screen that appears at the time, when you're asked to choose the user account and type in the password.